# Can OS report hd as encrypted when it isn't?

Tags: password

I got the message "cannot find file /boot/vmlinuz{version numbers)" after I updated to the latest kernel then went into /boot and deleted files to make space for the next update. My boot partition is small.
When I booted from a live CD there was the icon of a padlock emblazoned on the icon for that drive, which the OS recognizes but tells me is encrypted.
I only use one pass word for 90% of what I do, because I'm lazy and not paranoid about someone hacking my journals etc.
If I did encrypt the drive when installing 16.01, what would be the requirement; at least 8 characters?; at least one symbol, must contain at least one upper case...If I knew this then I might know how I altered that password to conform...thanks, I have a year and a half worth of my original music in Audacity files on that drive...
Let me save you the typing of: "You should back up regularly, dude."
I will from now on.